# Infragistics XamDataGrid Group By on load in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics, xamdatagrid

How can I set a Group By on Load for a given property for the XamDataGrid from Infragistics, and making the view of this uncollapsed with the ability to collapse the group disabled?
If this is possible I would know how I can hide the Group By small button as well.

My environment is WPF and C#.

Comment: Are you using infragistic data grid ?

Comment: @VishalParekh Yes I am using that data grid.

Comment: So you are able to achieve this by using ListCollectionView and add GroupDescriptions into it and apply ListCollectionView as item source it will generate group with column name which is defined in GroupDescriptions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

In Xaml,

```
<igDP:XamDataGrid x:Name="xdgSample" DataSource="{Binding SampleCollection}" InitializeRecord="xdgSample_InitializeRecord">
                                <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
                                    <igDP:FieldLayout>     
                                        <igDP:Field Name="field1" Label="Field1"/>
                                        <igDP:Field Name="field2" Label="Field2"/>
                                        <igDP:Field Name="field3" Label="Field3"/>
                                        <igDP:Field Name="field4" Label="Field4"/>
                                        <igDP:Field Name="field5" Label="Field5"/>                                   
                                    </igDP:FieldLayout>
                                </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
                                <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
                                    <igDP:FieldLayoutSettings AllowFieldMoving="No" 
                                                      AllowDelete="False"
                                                      AutoGenerateFields="False" 
                                                      AutoFitMode="ExtendLastField"
                                                      SelectionTypeRecord="Single" 
                                                      FilterUIType="LabelIcons"
                            GroupByExpansionIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed">
                                    </igDP:FieldLayoutSettings>
                                </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
                            </igDP:XamDataGrid>
```

In codebehind,

```
Private ObservableCollection<SampleBO> sampleCollection;

Public ObservableCollection<SampleBO> SampleCollection
{
    get
    {
        return this.sampleCollection;
    }   
}
```

You can put below code to load and grouping data in Window Loaded event or Constructor,

```
this.sampleCollection = your collection/List;
this.OnPropertyChange("SampleCollection");

this.xdgSample.FieldLayouts[0].SortedFields.Add(new FieldSortDescription
                        {
                            IsGroupBy = true,
                            Field = this.xamInputList.FieldLayouts[0].Fields["field2"],
                            Direction = System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending
                        });

                        this.xdgSample.FieldLayoutSettings.HeaderPlacement = HeaderPlacement.OnTopOnly;
                        this.xdgSample.FieldLayoutSettings.HeaderPlacementInGroupBy = HeaderPlacementInGroupBy.WithDataRecords;
```

Also,for expanded groups,use below event,it's for expanding group initially.

```
private void xdgSample_InitializeRecord(object sender, Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.Events.InitializeRecordEventArgs e)    
{    
if (e.Record.NestingDepth == 0)    
{    
    e.Record.IsExpanded = true;    
}    
}
```

Comment: It took a while to understand how to trigger the `xdgSample_InitializeRecord()`, but found out that it had to be done from `<igDP:XamDataGrid (...) InitializeRecords="xdgSample_InitializeRecord"`. If you could change `this.xdgSample.FieldLayoutSettings.HeaderPlacementInGroupBy = HeaderPlacementInGroupBy.WithDataRecords;` to `this.xdgSample.FieldLayoutSettings.HeaderPlacementInGroupBy = HeaderPlacementInGroupBy.OnTopOnly;` I will mark your answer as accepted. This as others won't be confused =)

Comment: Here,in question you have not mention about HeaderPlacement,so I had set it by my own. You can set HeaderPlacementInGroupBy property according to your requirement.

Comment: Thats my fault, I see that I did not mention the position of the Headers. But would you add the `InitializeRecords` in the `XamDataGrid`. That I think could confuse people as it won't work if not added.

Comment: Thank you very much! I know I asked for a lot when I wanted you to edit your post before accepting it. The thing is that I've come over a lot of posts which where accepted though it did not work in my case because someone left something out, and I didn't have the experience to figure it out =)